# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present error in AJAX Request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api, rest

```
  $.ajax({
            url: 'http://test.aegi.com/rest/social/update/@ViewBag.orgId?access_token=6fWV564u7rATh8=',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: [{
                "message": "It's party time",
                "messageType": "NEW",
                "gmtTimeDate": "2014-12-21 23:59:59",
                "soAccts": [{
                    "accountId": "74470431",
                    "soAccountType": "FBPAGE"
                }]
            }],

            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }

        });
```

When i'm trying to send this request `AJAX`  i'm getting an error : `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present`.
 But on dhc chrome extension when i put the same above data in body section and send the request then i get a success response. Am i doing anything wrong here?

Comment: Is your app running on any server? or checking with html file?

Comment: my application is running on my local server and the api is running on different server

Answer (score 1):

Modern Browser prohibit cross origin request hence they needs 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' response header to be present , if not then you receive that error.

While chrome extension like postman circumvent this restriction.

If you have an access to server then you should add  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' into response header or using jsonp.

Check CORS for more info.

Comment: i'm using post request and jsonp works with get request and even tried this but still not working : 
 var headers = {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
    };
and in ajax :  headers: headers,

Comment: 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' should be put in the server response and not request.

Comment: ok, but how to overcome this issue? is there anything wrong in the format of  json i'm sending?

Comment: no issue with you request, are you able to change server response ?

Comment: server is responding with a bad request and there is a DHC plugin in chrome when i paste the data there server response is success.

Comment: server is not responding with bad request, what browser does before any cross origin request is to send "pre-flight" request ( OPTIONS ) to determine if it is allow to do cross origin or not. DHC plugin doesn't do that.

Comment: are you able to modified your api server ? If yes, what platform that you use ?

Comment: i'm using asp.net MVC

Comment: Check http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

Answer (score 0):

Try by adding header :

```
headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*' }
* in above line will allow access to all domains.

headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://www.example.com' }
For allowing access to specific domain only.
```

**Edited answer:**

```
beforeSend: function(xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
}
```

Comment: Access-Control-Allow-Origin is for response and not request

Comment: Exactly what @kwan245 said. Your addition of the header won't do anything. It's the server-side that controls what can access it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use json dataType:"jsonp" in your ajax request